# Can't see a post preview

Tags: support, status-norepro

I can't see the preview of my questions or answers in Waterfox/Firefox while I'm writing them. I didn't change any settings, it started just a couple of days ago.

I tried deleting cookies but it didn't help.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Norepro, FF 11.0/Win7 x64.

Comment: What? :/
Did you mean to say you have no problem or did I misunderstand? BTW, the problem resolved on its own, no updates, no restarts, no reinstalls. Don't know why but I'm glad it did.

Answer (score 6):

WHile it's not happening to me, a couple of days ago is when Firefox 11 came out.  So it's possible the upgrade for you has broken something.  You could perhaps try the Beta or Aurora streams?  Alternatively a full reinstall of it, perhaps.

Also check on meta.stackexchange - there may be others experiencing the same thing!

Comment: I thought it might be that. Will use Chrome for stackexchange while waiting for a next Waterfox update.